# Are CSS @media query statements cascading properties specified in em unit?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, screen-resolution

Assuming there are two CSS @media queries as in the following sample:

```
@media screen and (min-width:720px) {body{font-size: 2em;}}
@media screen and (max-width:1280px) {body{font-size: 0.5em;}}
```

what would be expected `body` `font-size` if page is viewed in the device with 1280 x 800 screen resolution (namely: `2em`, `0.5em` or `1em`)?

For added clarity: in this context 'cascading' means that the result will be calculated by consequently applying all matching cases, i.e. **2em * 0.5em**.

By analogy, having CSS like this:

```
TEST1<div style="font-size:2em">TEST2<div style="font-size:0.5em">TEST3</div></div>
```

the `font-size` of inner **TEST3** text will be `1em` (2em * 0.5em = `1em`, i.e. the same as of original **TEST1**).
See on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bj3xsanq/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, font size will end up being `0.5em`, because the second `font-size` definition overrides the first one according to the usual CSS rules.

And if you would change the order of the two media queries, then the resulting font size would be `2em`.

---

Here's a snippet which demonstrates this.

Note that the text will be bold (1st media query), italic (2nd media query) and red (the definition from the 2nd media query "wins" according to the usual CSS rules).

Font-size will be set to `0.5em`, because the 2nd definition overwrites the first one (*NOT* `1em`, as it would be if the 2nd definition would be applied cumulatively "on top" of the 1st one).

```css
@media screen and (max-width:10000px) {
  p.styled {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1px) {
  p.styled {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 0.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="styled">Text with styles from both media queries applied.</p>
<p>Text with no styles applied.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. I've added some clarity to the definition, so it looks like  the last query will override all previous matches, so semantically its sort of exclusive logic (only one from many). Just to make sure that cascading will not happen, like 2em*0.5em ending up with 1em because both cases match the condition.

Comment: If both queries match, then the last definition will overwrite the first one. It's subject to the usual CSS rules — you can think of media queries like "the rendering engine preserves all matched queries' contents, and removes all non-matched ones, in a kind of _preprocessing step_".  I've updated the answer to demonstrate that the multiplication doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks again. I think it's right for all other properties, but em unit means a multiplier that inner element should apply to the value of parent element, so in this case it probably should be 2em*0.5em = 1em, as in the sample on jsfiddle.

Comment: I've changed the units to `em` and included an unstyled text for reference. As you can see, the units are _not_ multiplied.

Comment: Yes, you are right.Thanks for answering my question. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

It will be 2em until 1179px if you do:

```
@media screen and (min-width : 280px){
body{font-size: 2em;}
@media screen and (min-width : 1179px){
body{font-size: .5em;}}
```

It all depends how you declare the break points, sometimes odd things seem to happen, but it is just all in the break points declaration.
I have found this approach the easiest for mobile first.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I was asking. Best regards,